# Is there a way to use svnsync with a repository loaded from a dump file?

Tags: svn

I created a new repository A.

Ran svnsync init with repository B as the source.

Loaded a dump file from B (rev 0 to 1690 of 1801) to A.

Then tried to run svnsync. My thinking was that svnsync could pick up where the dump file left off.

This is the error:

```
svnsync: Destination HEAD (1690) is not the last merged revision (0); have you committed to the destination without using svnsync?
```

Is there a way to make svnsync think it has already synced up to the current rev?

Answer (score 6):

After the loading the dump file, you can run this command:

```
svn propset --revprop -r0 svn:sync-last-merged-rev 1690 https://mysvn.com/svn
```

All SYNC properties are stored in `[repository]\db\revprops\0\0`. You can inspect and modify other properties there, but do it with caution. You can easily corrupt the settings. I recommend using the command line rather than manually editing the 0 file.